# Powershell script to run another powershell script and wait till over

Tags: powershell, scripting

i'm trying to run a script which will run another powershell script. 
i need the first script to continue only after the other one is over.
something like:

start Copy.ps1 
wait till Copy.ps1 is done
continue with the script

tried using the Invoke-Expression but it doesn't have wait parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you easily can do it by calling the file like this:

```
<#
  here is some awesome code
#>

# Call P$ Script here
& C:\Path\To\CopyScript.ps1

<#
  awesome code continues here
#>
```

it will call the whole script in Copy.ps1 and continues after copy.ps1 finished.

Other method is you set the whole script in copy.ps1 into a function.

in CopyScript.ps1:

```
function MyCopyFunction(){

  # all code inside the Copy.ps1 is here
   
}
```

And in your new File:

```
# Call P$ Script here
& C:\Path\To\CopyScript.ps1

# then call the function
MyCopyFunction
```

Greetz Eldo.Ob

Comment: Unless you specifically want to run the script directly in the caller's scope - so as to load function, alias, variable _definitions_ from there - you should use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-),  instead of `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).

Comment: In cases where the dot-sourcing operator _is_ called for, follow it by a _space_ to avoid the awkward need for wrapping the script path in `(...)`: `. C:\Path\To\Copy.ps1`

Comment: Thanks for updating, but now the `(...)` is superfluous and it's still not clear why you're dot-sourcing (`. `; running in the _same_ scope - rather than calling (`& `; running in a _child_ scope). Also note that to-end-of-line comments in PowerShell use `#`, not `//`.

Answer (score 6):

From https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell_from_don_jones-24/19166/wait-for-powershell-script-to-complete-before-starting-another-script

You can just put an ampersand in front of the script name, e.g.

```
& .\Copy.ps1
```