# Wait for multiple simultaneous powershell commands in other sessions to finish before running next commands

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a master powershell script to do the following:

1. Run commands in 3 other powershell sessions (they all go for about ~1h - I'd like them to run concurrently, so that the jobs they do can all get done at the same time)
2. Wait for **all 3** other powershell sessions to finish
3. Continue on with remaining commands in the initial powershell window

#### Extremely simple example

My real use case is similar to the following, except the times always vary, `ECHO "hi"` should happen only once all the other (3) commands have finished (in this case we know they'll take 10000 seconds, but in my actual use case this varies a lot). Also note, it's not clear which of the 3 commands will take the longest each time.

```
start powershell { TIMEOUT 2000 }
start powershell { TIMEOUT 3000 }
start powershell { TIMEOUT 10000 }
ECHO "hi"
```

I can see ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55717353/5783745)) that I can put an `&` in front of the command in order to tell powershell to wait until it's complete before progressing to subsequent commands. However, I do not know how to do so with 3 simultaneous commands

Comment: have you looked at powershell jobs yet? they run in parallel and the main script can check for results with the various `*-Job` cmdlets.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I am new to this and have never heard of it. I will google

Comment: it sounds like that will do what you need ... good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It looks more complicated but sounds like it does exactly what I'm after. Are you able to provide a quick example of how the code would appear for the example in the question (I will then try to adapt it for my use case)? Also, what happens to the output seen in the powershell terminal, if 3 processes are running simultaneously does that mean all the output gets strewn in together? (i.e. in the one window?)

Comment: the jobs run in their own process. you get NOTHING from them until you get the results by using one of the cmdlets involved. i've never used them myself - no need. there are several articles on the use of those cmdlets when i search for `powershell how to use start-job`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are indeed looking for **Powershell [*background jobs*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs)**, as [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) advises.

However, **jobs are heavy-handed, because each job runs in its own *process***, which introduces *significant overhead*, and *can also result in loss of type fidelity* (due to PowerShell's XML-based serialization infrastructure being involved - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375)).

**The [`ThreadJob` module](https://github.com/PaulHigin/PSThreadJob) offers a lightweight alternative based on *threads***.
It comes with PowerShell [Core] v6+ and in Windows PowerShell can be installed on demand with, e.g., 
`Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`.<sup>[1]</sup>

You simply call `Start-ThreadJob` instead of `Start-Job`, and use the standard `*-Job` cmdlets to *manage* such thread jobs - the same way you'd manage a regular background job.

Here's an example:

```
$startedAt = [datetime]::UtcNow

# Define the commands to run as [thread] jobs.
$commands = { $n = 2; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }, 
            { $n = 3; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }, 
            { $n = 10; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }

# Start the (thread) jobs.
# You could use `Start-Job` here, but that would be more resource-intensive
# and make the script run considerably longer.
$jobs = $commands | Foreach-Object { Start-ThreadJob $_ }

# Wait until all jobs have completed, passing their output through as it
# is received, and automatically clean up afterwards.
$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob


"All jobs completed. Total runtime in secs.: $(([datetime]::UtcNow - $startedAt).TotalSeconds)"
```

The above yields something like the following; note that the individual commands' output is reported *as it becomes available*, but execution of the calling script doesn't continue until all commands have completed:

```
I ran for 2 secs.
I ran for 3 secs.
I ran for 10 secs.
All jobs completed. Total runtime in secs.: 10.2504931
```

**Note**: In this simple case, it's obvious which output came from which command, but more typically the output from the various jobs will run *unpredictably interleaved*, which makes it difficult to interpret the output - see the next section for a solution.

As you can see, the overhead introduced for the thread-based parallel execution in the background is minimal - overall execution took only a little longer than 10 seconds, the runtime of the longest-running of the 3 commands.

If you were to use the process-based `Start-Job` instead, the overall execution time might look something like this, showing the significant overhead introduced, especially the first time you run a background job in a session:

```
All jobs completed. Total runtime in secs.: 18.7502717
```

That is, at least on the first invocation in a session, the benefits of parallel execution in the background were negated - execution took longer than *sequential* execution would have taken in this case.

While subsequent process-based background jobs in the same session run faster, the overhead is still significantly higher than it is for thread-based jobs.

---

#### Synchronizing the job output streams

If you want show output from the background commands *per command*, you need to collect output separately.

Note: In a console window (terminal), this requires you to wait until all commands have completed before you can show the output (because there is no way to show multiple output streams simultaneously via in-place updating, at least with the regular output commands).

```
$startedAt = [datetime]::UtcNow

$commands = { $n = 1; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }, 
            { $n = 2; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }, 
            { $n = 3; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }

$jobs = $commands | Foreach-Object { Start-ThreadJob $_ }

# Wait until all jobs have completed.
$null = Wait-Job $jobs

# Collect the output individually for each job and print it.
foreach ($job in $jobs) {
  "`n--- Output from {$($job.Command)}:"
  Receive-Job $job
} 

"`nAll jobs completed. Total runtime in secs.: $('{0:N2}' -f ([datetime]::UtcNow - $startedAt).TotalSeconds)"
```

The above will print something like this:

```
--- Output from { $n = 1; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }:
I ran for 1 secs.

--- Output from { $n = 2; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }:
I ran for 2 secs.

--- Output from { $n = 3; Start-Sleep $n; "I ran for $n secs." }:
I ran for 3 secs.

All jobs completed. Total runtime in secs.: 3.09
```

---

#### Using `Start-Process` to run the commands in separate windows

On Windows, you can use `Start-Process` (whose alias is `start`) to run commands in a *new window*, which is also *asynchronous* by default, i.e., serially *launched* commands do run *in parallel*.

In a limited form, this allows you to monitor command-specific output in *real time*, but it comes with the following **caveats**:

- You'll have to manually activate the new windows individually to see the output being generated.
- The output is only visible while a command is running; on completion, its window closes automatically, so you can't inspect the output after the fact.

  - To work around that you'd have to use something like `Tee-Object` in your PowerShell cmdlet in order to also capture output in a *file*, which the caller could later inspect.
  - This is also the only way to make the output available *programmatically*, albeit only as *text*.
- Passing PowerShell commands to `powershell.exe` via `Start-Process` requires you to pass your commands as *strings* (rather than script blocks) and has annoying parsing requirements, such as the need to escape `"` chars. as `\"` (sic) - see below.
- Last and not least, using `Start-Process` also introduces significant processing overhead (though with very long-running commands that may not matter).

```
$startedAt = [datetime]::UtcNow

# Define the commands - of necessity - as *strings*.
# Note the unexpected need to escape the embedded " chars. as \"
$commands = '$n = 1; Start-Sleep $n; \"I ran for $n secs.\"',
            '$n = 2; Start-Sleep $n; \"I ran for $n secs.\"',
            '$n = 3; Start-Sleep $n; \"I ran for $n secs.\"'

# Use `Start-Process` to launch the commands asynchronously,
# in a new window each (Windows only).
# `-PassThru` passes an object representing the newly created process through.
$procs = $commands | ForEach-Object { Start-Process -PassThru powershell -Args '-c', $_ }

# Wait for all processes to exit.
$procs.WaitForExit()


"`nAll processes completed. Total runtime in secs.: $('{0:N2}' -f ([datetime]::UtcNow - $startedAt).TotalSeconds)"
```

---

<sup>[1] In Windows PowerShell v3 and v4, `Install-Module` isn't available by default, because these versions do not come with the `PowerShellGet` module. However, this module can be installed on demand, as detailed in [Installing PowerShellGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget#for-computers-running-powershell-30-or-powershell-40)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer to the question, using jobs.

```
start-job { sleep 2000 }
start-job { sleep 3000 }
start-job { sleep 10000 }
get-job | wait-job
echo hi
```

Here's another way.  Start being an alias for start-process.  You could use timeout instead of sleep.  Running timeout three times looks pretty cool actually, but it can mess up some of the output.

```
$a = start -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'a done'} -PassThru
$b = start -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'b done'} -PassThru
$c = start -NoNewWindow powershell {timeout 10; 'c done'} -PassThru
$a,$b,$c | wait-process
'hi'

b done
c done

a done
hi
```

Here's an attempt at workflow.

```
function sleepfor($time) { sleep $time; "sleepfor $time done"}

workflow work {
  parallel {
    sleepfor 3
    sleepfor 2
    sleepfor 1
  }
  'hi'
}
    
work 

sleepfor 1 done
sleepfor 2 done
sleepfor 3 done
hi
```

Or just:

```
function sleepfor($time) { sleep $time; "sleepfor $time done"}

workflow work2 {
  foreach -parallel ($i in 1..3) { sleepfor 10 }
  'hi'
}

work2 # runs in about 13 seconds

sleepfor 10 done
sleepfor 10 done
sleepfor 10 done
hi
```

Api attempt with 3 runspaces:

```
$a =  [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript{sleep 5;'a done'}
$b =  [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript{sleep 5;'b done'}
$c =  [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript{sleep 5;'c done'}
$r1,$r2,$r3 = ($a,$b,$c).begininvoke()
$a.EndInvoke($r1); $b.EndInvoke($r2); $c.EndInvoke($r3)
($a,$b,$c).dispose()

a done
b done
c done
```

Remote invoke-command (elevated prompt):

```
invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost { sleep 5; 'done' }

done
done
done
```

Comment: Workflow is not supported in PowerShell 6+