# How to get values from workflow parallel code block?

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I'm trying to run two `Invoke-Sqlcmd` in parallel and then wait all the results.

```
$server1 = '...'
$server2 = '...'

workflow work {
  parallel {
    $r1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server1 'select 1 a'
    $r2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server2 'select 2 a'
  }
}
work
# do something with $r1 and $r2. How to access the variables here?
```

1. How to pass `$server1` and `$server2` to the code block?
2. How to get `$r1` and `$r2` from the parallel block?

Comment: Given that workflows are obsolescent (they're no longer supported in PowerShell _Core_), I suggest looking into `Start-ThreadJob` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612574/45375).

Comment: You can pass in servers with a `param ()`.  Not sure how to get the results except `$result = work $server1 $server2`.  Maybe jobs is easier.

Comment: @mklement0, I tried ThreadJob. But it doesn't work with Invoke-SqlCmd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609740/threadjob-the-writeobject-and-writeerror-cannot-be-called-from-outside-the-over

Comment: Interesting, @ca9163d9: I think the problem is a bug in `Invoke-SqlCmd`, as detailed in my comment on your linked question. You can work around the problem with regular child-process-based background jobs (`Start-Job`), but note that they have a lot more overhead than thread jobs - for long-running SQL queries that won't matter, however.

Answer (score 1):

So pass in servers with param, and return a hashtable of both results.

```
$server1 = '...'
$server2 = '...'

workflow work {
  param ($server1, $server2)
  parallel {
    @{r1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server1 'select 1 a'}
    @{r2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server2 'select 2 a'}
  }
}
$r = work $server1 $server2
$r.r1
$r.r2
```

Comment: It works. However, I will use `Start-ThreadJob` as @mklement0 mentioned that workflow is obsolescent in the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's still parallel.