# Powershell start-job scope

Tags: powershell, scope, start-job, scriptblock

I have a long script. i have a function for logging:

```
function Log ([string]$Content){
    $Date = Get-Date
    Add-Content -Path $LogPath -Value ("$Date : $Content")
}
```

In some point at the script i have the need to run jobs in parallel.
I have a list of computer names and i need to use psexec to each one of them. this should be done as jobs to to run in parallel

```
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        
        Log "$line Has called"
            $Program_List = gc $USERS_DB_PATH\$line.txt | select -Skip 1
            if (Test-Connection $line -Quiet) {
                    ForEach ($program in $Program_List){
                    Log "$line $program"
                    #"line $line bot is $bot pwd is $pwd"
                    psexec \\"$line" -u bla.local\"$bot" -p $pwd cmd bla
                    
                    }
            }
            else{
                  Log "Cannot Connect to $line"
            }
        
        
        }
        #Remove-Item "$USERS_DB_PATH\$line.txt"


}
```

I understand this is something to do with Scope but how can I make this scriptblock see the function Log and all the neccesery variables? they all come up empty

Comment: Think of it as remote variables. So try `$using:myvar` when referencing variables outside of it.

Comment: I Actually used $using:var  but that didnt work, still came empty, also how can i use this way to call a function and not a var?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Reference variables from the *caller*'s scope via the `$using:` scope.
- *Recreate* your `Log` function in the context of the background job, using
  `$function:Log = "$using:function:Log"`

```bash
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

  # Required in Windows PowerShell only (if needed).
  # Change to the same working directory as the caller.
  Set-Location -LiteralPath ($using:PWD).ProviderPath

  # Recreate the Log function.
  $function:Log = "$using:function:Log"
        
  # All variable values from the *caller*'s scope must be $using: prefixed.
  Log "$using:line Has called"
  # ...        
        
}
```

- Read on for an explanation.
- See the **bottom section** for **better alternatives to `Start-Job`**: **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)** and **`ForEach-Object -Parallel`** (PowerShell (Core) 7+ only).

---

**A background job runs in an invisible PowerShell *child process***, i.e. a separate `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) `pwsh` (PowerShell (Core) 7+) process.

Such a child process:

- does not load `$PROFILE` files.
- **knows nothing about the caller's state**; that is, it doesn't have access to the caller's variables, functions, aliases, ... defined in the session; **only *environment* variables are inherited from the caller**.

Conversely, this means that ***only* the following *commands* are available by default in background jobs**:

- external programs and `*.ps1` scripts, via the directories listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable.
- commands in modules available via the [module-autoloading feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules?view=powershell-7.2), from directories listed in the `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable (which has a default module).

---

**Passing caller-state information to background jobs:**

- **Variables**:

  - While you cannot pass variables *as such* to background jobs, you can pass their *values*, using the `$using:` scope; in other words: you can *get the value of* but not *update* a variable in the caller's scope - see the conceptual about_Remote_Variables.
  - Alternatively, pass the value as an *argument* via [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)'s `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter, which the `-ScriptBlock` argument must then access in the usual manner: either via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) or via explicitly declared parameters, using a [`param()` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters).
- **`function`s**:

  - Analogously, you cannot pass a function *as such*, but only a function's *body*, and the simplest way to do that is via [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375); e.g. to get the body of function `foo`, use `$function:foo`; to pass it to a background job (or remote call), use `"$using:function:foo"`.
  - Since namespace variable notation can also be used to *assign* values, assigning to `$function:foo` creates or updates a function named `foo`, so that `$function:foo = $using:function:foo` effectively recreates a `foo` function in the background session.

    - Note that while `$function:foo` returns the function body as a `[scriptblock]` instance, `$using:function:foo`, turns into a *string* during serialization (see [GitHub issue #11698](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11698); however, fortunately you can also create function bodies from *strings*.
    - As such, **enclosing `$using:function:foo` in `"..."`** isn't strictly necessary for `Start-Job`; it is, however, **required for `Start-ThreadJob`**, because in the absence of serialization in *thread*-based parallelism, `$using:function:foo` *is* a `[scriptblock]` instance, but is associated with the *caller's* runspace and must therefore be *rebuilt from a string* in the job context (otherwise, state corruption can occur).
    - That `Start-ThreadJob` even *allows* such script-block references may be an *oversight*, and the PowerShell v7+ **`ForEach-Object -Parallel`** feature (which shares technical underpinning with `Start-ThreadJob`) explicitly *disallows* them, necessitating a **workaround** via a helper variable that first stringifies the script block in the caller's scope - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61273544/45375).
- **`class`es**

  - While there is *no* namespace variable notation for *classes*, you can work around that via a helper script block: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76846647/45375).
- **Working directory**:

  - In *Windows PowerShell* background jobs use a *fixed* working directory: the users `Documents` folder. To ensure that the background job uses the same directory as the caller, call
    `Set-Location -LiteralPath ($using:PWD).ProviderPath` as the first statement from inside the script block passed to `-ScriptBlock`.
  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* background job now - fortunately - use the same working directory as the caller.

Caveat re **type fidelity**:

- Since values must be marshaled *across process boundaries*, serialization and deserialization of values is of necessity involved. Background jobs use the same serialization infrastructure as PowerShell's [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote), which - with the exception of a handful of well-known types, including .NET primitive types - results in *loss of type fidelity*, both on passing values *to* background jobs and receiving output *from* them - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375)

---

#### Preferable alternative to *background* jobs: *thread* jobs, via `Start-ThreadJob`:

*PowerShell (Core) 7+* comes with the `ThreadJob` module, which offers the **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet**; in *Windows PowerShell* you can [install it on demand](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob/).

- Additionally, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* offers essentially the same functionality as an extension to the **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** cmdlet, via the **`-Parallel`** parameter, which executes a script block passed to it in a separate thread for each input object.

`Start-ThreadJob` fully integrates with PowerShell's other job-management cmdlets, but uses *threads* (i.e. *in-process* concurrency) rather than *child processes*, which implies:

- much faster execution
- use of fewer resources
- no loss of type fidelity (though you can run into thread-safety issues and explicit synchronization may be required)

Also, the caller's working directory is inherited.

The need for `$using:` / `-ArgumentList` equally applies.

- For `ForEach-Object -Parallel` an improvement is being considered to allow copying the caller's state to the thread script blocks on an opt-in basis  - see [GitHub issue #12240](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12240).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440248/45375) provides an overview of `ForEach-Object -Parallel` and compares and contrasts `Start-Job` and `Start-ThreadJob`.