# How to call a class object in powershell jobs

Tags: powershell, class, jobs

I have created test PowerShell class. My plan is to run parallels background jobs to create class objects and execute methods in the class

```
class Test {

    [String]$ComputerName
    
    
    [String]TestMrParameter() {

        if ($this.ComputerName -eq 'jhon'){throw "Bad thing happened"}
        
        return $this.ComputerName 

    }
}

$names = @('david', 'jhon', 'mark','tent')
$jobs = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

function TestMrParameter2 {
    param (
        [String]$name
    )
    [Test]$obj = [Test]::new()
    $obj.ComputerName = $name
    Write-Host $name + "TestMrParameter2 Function Reached!!!"
    $output=$obj.TestMrParameter()
    Write-Host "Output of the Test class is" + $output
}


foreach ($name in $names) {

    $out = Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${Function:TestMrParameter2} -ArgumentList $name
    $jobs.Add($out) | out-null

}
```

I get my jobs as completed but not with my expectations. Therefore, I checked each job details to get more insights and I found this error on each job. It cannot identify the class to create the object out of it.

```
Unable to find type [Test].
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Test:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
 
The property 'ComputerName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can 
be set.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered already on here:

[How do I Start a job of a function i just defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162090/how-do-i-start-a-job-of-a-function-i-just-defined)

via the initialisation script switch. Either that, or put your class function in the Job script itself.

Comment: I added the class into the initialization script and create the instance from the class in script function. It works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- The following doesn't just apply to the child-process-based jobs created by [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job), but analogously also to the generally preferable *thread*-based jobs created with [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)<sup>[1]</sup> and the thread-based parallelism available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)  `-Parallel`, as well as to PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) - in short: it applies to any scenario in which PowerShell executes out-of-runspace (in a different runspace).

---

**PowerShell's [background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs)** run in an out-of-process runspace (a hidden child process) and therefore **share no state with the caller**.

Therefore, definitions created by the caller in-session - such as functions and  [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) definitions - are *not* visible to background jobs.

**Short of providing these definitions via *script files* (`*.ps1`) or *modules* that the job would have to [dot-source (`.` )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) or import, you'll have to *duplicate* the definitions  of interest in the job's script block.**

- Note: [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) (as well as well as [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)) optionally supports passing a script block to its **`-InitializationScript`** parameter, which allows initialization that precedes execution of the script block passed to `-ScriptBlock`. While this can be a helpful separation for maintenance purposes, it is currently (Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) v7.3.6) severely hampered by a **bug**: `$using:` references aren't supported in `-InitializationScript` script blocks, which makes it impossible to reference values and definitions from the caller's scope.

  - See [GitHub issue #4530](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4530); the fact that the bug report was created in 2017 suggests that fixing the bug has low priority.

While you can reduce the duplication in the case of *functions* by referencing their bodies via the [`$using:scope`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76847044/45375) and the last snippet of sample code below - there is no analog for *classes*.

However, you can **avoid having to duplicate the `class` definition in the context of a job via a *helper script block***, as follows:

First, a **simplified, self-contained example** that shows the **`class` redefinition only**:

```bash
# Wrap the class definition in a helper script block ({ ... }).
$classDefScriptBlock = {
  class Test {
    [String]$ComputerName  
    [String]TestMrParameter() {
        if ($this.ComputerName -eq 'jhon'){throw "Bad thing happened"}        
        return $this.ComputerName   
    }
  }
}

# Define the class in the current scope by dot-sourcing the script block.
. $classDefScriptBlock

Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {

  # Recreate the script block and dot-source it in the job's scope.
  . ([scriptblock]::Create("$using:classDefScriptBlock"))

  # Now you can use the [Test] class:
  "The class name is: " + [Test].FullName

} | 
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The above outputs `The class name is: Test`, as intended, which implies that the `class` was successfully (re)defined in the context of the job.

---

Finally, a **self-contained example** that shows the **both `class` and `function` redefinitions**:

```bash
# Wrap the class definition in a helper script block ({ ... }).
$classDefScriptBlock = {
  class Test {
    [String]$ComputerName  
    [String]TestMrParameter() {
        if ($this.ComputerName -eq 'jhon'){throw "Bad thing happened"}        
        return $this.ComputerName   
    }
  }
}

# Define the class in the current scope by dot-sourcing the script block.
. $classDefScriptBlock

# Define a simplified function that uses the [Test] class.
# Unlike with classes, no extra effort is required on the caller's 
# side in order to be able to redefine the function in the job's context.
function TestMrParameter2 { 
  param($name)
  "Return value from class method: " + ([Test] @{ ComputerName = $name}).TestMrParameter()
}

Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {

  param (
    [string]$name
  )

  # Recreate the script block and dot-source it in the job's scope.
  . ([scriptblock]::Create("$using:classDefScriptBlock"))

  # Recreate the TestMrParameter2 function via a $using: reference
  # and namespace variable notation.
  $function:TestMrParameter2 = "$using:function:TestMrParameter2"

  # Now you can call the TestMrParameter2 function.
  TestMrParameter2 -Name $name

} -ArgumentList 'computer1' | 
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The above outputs `Return value from class method: computer1`, as intended, which implies that both the `class` and the `function` were successfully (re)defined in the context of the job.

---

<sup>[1] `Start-ThreadJob` is a lightweight, much faster *thread*-based alternative to the child-process-based regular background jobs created with `Start-Job`.
It comes with PowerShell (Core) 7+ and in Windows PowerShell can be installed on demand with, e.g., `Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`.
In most cases, thread jobs are the better choice, both for performance and type fidelity - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440248/45375) for why.</sup>