# Powershell, wait for first process to end

Tags: docker, powershell

Powershell script should exit if one of the main Processes stopped.

This script is the main Docker process. Docker container should stop if one of those Apps (`app1`, `app2`)stopped.

Current approach is to use Exit Events for one of the Apps and Wait-Process for the other. Is there a better approach?

```
$pApp1 = Start-Process -PassThru app1
$pApp2 = Start-Process -PassThru app2

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $pApp1 -EventName exited -Action {
    Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
    exit 1
}

Wait-Process -Id $pApp2.id
exit 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PowerShell 7.2.1, [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process), when given *multiple* processes, invariably waits for *all* of them to terminate before returning; potentially introducing an `-Any` switch so as to only wait for *any one* among them is the subject of [GitHub proposal #16972](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16972), which would simplify the solution to `Wait-Process -Any -Id $pApp1.id, $pApp2.id`

---

**Delegating waiting for the processes to exit to *thread* / *background* jobs** avoids the need for an event-based or periodic-polling solution.

```sh
# Start all processes asynchronously and get process-information 
# objects for them.
$allPs = 'app1', 'app2' | ForEach-Object { Start-Process -PassThru $_ }

# Start a thread job for each process that waits for that process to exit
# and then pass the process-info object for the terminated process through.
# Exit the overall pipeline once the first output object from one of the
# jobs is received.
$terminatedPs = $allPs | 
  ForEach-Object { Start-ThreadJob { $ps = $using:_; Wait-Process -Id $ps.Id; $ps } } |
    Receive-Job -Wait |
      Select-Object -First 1

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Process with ID $($terminatedPs.Id) exited."
exit 1
```

Note:

- I'm using he [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet, which offers a lightweight, much faster *thread*-based alternative to the child-process-based regular background jobs created with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job).
  It comes with *PowerShell (Core) 7+* and in *Windows PowerShell* can be installed on demand with, e.g., `Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`.
  In most cases, thread jobs are the better choice, both for performance and type fidelity - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440248/45375) for why.
- If `Start-ThreadJob` isn't available to you / cannot be installed, simply substitute `Start-Job` in the code above.

---

***PowerShell (Core) 7+*-only solution with `ForEeach-Object -Parallel`**:

PowerShell 7.0 introduced the `-Parallel` parameter to the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, which in essence brings thread-based parallelism to the *pipeline*; it is a way to create multiple, implicit thread jobs, one for each pipeline input object, that emit their output directly to the pipeline (albeit in no guaranteed order).

Therefore, the following simplified solution is possible:

```sh
# Start all processes asynchronously and get process-information 
# objects for them.
$allPs = 'app1', 'app2' | ForEach-Object { Start-Process -PassThru $_ }

$terminatedPs = $allPs | 
  ForEach-Object -Parallel { $_ | Wait-Process; $_  } |
    Select-Object -First 1

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Process with ID $($terminatedPs.Id) exited."
exit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the `HasExited` property on either of them to change:

```
$apps = 'app1','app2' |ForEach-Object { Start-Process $_ -PassThru }

while(@($apps |Where HasExited -eq $true).Count -lt 1){
  Write-Host "Waiting for one of them to exit..."
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```