# PowerShell - How to find which paths a given command will execute against?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1, file-monitoring

## Problem

I have the command `Get-Content -Path $SearchPath -Wait | Select-String -Pattern $SearchTerm` which is used to search through **debug file(s)** for common **search terms** and display them live to the user.

The `$SearchPath` & `$SearchTerm` are configured from **user inputs**.

I would like to list out the **files** that will be searched to the user before starting the search.

---

## What I have tried

#### Attempt #1

`Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

The problem with this command is that it lists both **files** & **directories**.
However, only **files** will be searched in the `Get-Content` command.

#### Attempt #2

Since I know that all my files end with `.log`, I added in a regex check for this to eliminate the **directories**, like so:

`Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath | Where-Object { $_.Name -match [regex]'([a-zA-Z0-9])*.log' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

The problem with this command is that if `$SearchPath` is `C:\Path\To\The\*` it will list *only* the files in that **directory**, but not **subdirectories**.
However, the original `Get-Content` command will check **subdirectories**.

E.g. It would list `C:\Path\To\The\DebugLog.log`, but not `C:\Path\To\The\SubDir\DebugLog.log`, even though `Get-Content` would search it.

#### Attempt #3

Okay, so my next thought is that I should add `-Recurse` to check further **directories**, like so:

`Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match [regex]'([a-zA-Z0-9])*.log' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

This solves the first problem, but now if `$SearchPath` is `C:\Path\To\The\DebugLog.log`, it will list both `C:\Path\To\The\DebugLog.log` & `C:\Path\To\The\Subfolder\DebugLog.log`. But the original `Get-Content` command will only search `C:\Path\To\The\DebugLog.log`.

---

## Question

How can I check which **files** the `Get-Content` command will search before executing it?

Is `Get-ChildItem` the right command for this, or is there a better option?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` supports a `-File` parameter that causes it to return only files, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-file).  This will work with `-Recurse`, so you can search a directory and subdirectories for files only.

Comment: Note that with `$SearchPath = 'C:\Path\To\The\*'`, `Get-Content -Path $SearchPath` will _not_ search subdirectories. Passing a _directory_ path to `Get-Content` results in an error.

Comment: @boxdog Thank you, that is very helpful!

Comment: @mklement0 Oh, I was misunderstanding that. Thank you! Is there a way it, or another command, search subdirectories?

Comment: @Tyler, are you sure you want to filter on alphanumeric only filenames? That would skip files that contain any other character. It would not find `2023-09-28.log`. If you want all *.log files, use `-Filter *.log` on the `Get-ChildItem` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with `$SearchPath = 'C:\Path\To\The\*'`, `Get-Content -Path $SearchPath` will *not* search subdirectories. Passing a *directory* path to Get-Content results in an error.

- To limit retrieval of file-system items to *files*, use the `-File` switch.
- To limit *recursive* retrieval to a *specified depth*, use the `-Depth` parameter (which *implies* the `-Recurse` switch)

Therefore, in order to retrieve all `*.log` files in the current directory and its *immediate* subdirectories, use the following:

```bash
$logFilesOfInterest =
  Get-ChildItem -File -Depth 1 -Filter *.log
```

You can then pass these files to your `Get-Content` pipeline, using either of the following approaches:

```bash
# Either: Use the pipeline.
$logFilesOfInterest | Get-Content -Wait | Select-String -Pattern $SearchTerm

# Or: Pass them as *arguments*.
Get-Content -LiteralPath $logFilesOfInterest.FullName -Wait | 
  Select-String -Pattern $SearchTerm
```

However, **in neither case will `-Wait` work as you intend**:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Wait` switch effectively only supports *one* input file: it reads the *first* one given and then indefinitely waits for it to have more data appended to it, without reading the *other* files; it only moves on to the next file if the file currently being monitored happens to get *deleted*.

To **monitor *multiple* files *simultaneously*, you'll need to use a form of *parallelism***, which **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** can provide via the `-Parallel` parameter of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```bash
# PSv7+ only.

$logFilesOfInterest =
  Get-ChildItem -File -Depth 1 -Filter *.log 

$searchTerm = '.' # Specify your search term here.

$logFilesOfInterest |
  ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit $logFilesOfInterest.Count -Parallel {
    $_ | Get-Content -Wait | Select-String -Pattern $using:searchTerm 
  }
```

- `-ThrottleLimit $logFilesOfInterest.Count` ensures that a thread is spun up for *every* file to be monitored *right away*.
- `$using:SearchTerm` is required in order to refer to the `$SearchTerm` variable in the *caller's* scope.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop monitoring.

---

In ***Windows PowerShell***, you'll have to use background [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs), which is more cumbersome:

```bash
$logFilesOfInterest =
  Get-ChildItem -File -Depth 1 -Filter *.log 

$searchTerm = '.' # Specify your search term here.

$logFilesOfInterest |
  ForEach-Object -OutVariable jobs {
    Start-Job {
      Get-Content -LiteralPath ($using:_).FullName -Wait | 
        Select-String -Pattern $using:searchTerm |
        ForEach-Object Line
    }
  } |
  Receive-Job -Wait
```

- Use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop monitoring.
- After doing so, you can clean up the jobs with `$jobs | Remove-Job -Force` (the `$jobs` variable containing all launched jobs was created with `-OutVariable jobs`)
- Note the use of `ForEach-Object Line`, which is necessary to work around a *bug* in Windows PowerShell, which causes direct `Select-String` output not to surface via `Receive-Job` (PowerShell (Core) no longer has this problem.)
- As an aside (it won't make much difference here):

  - The [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet offers a lightweight, much faster *thread*-based alternative to the child-process-based regular background jobs created with `Start-Job`.
    It comes with PowerShell (Core) 7+ and in Windows PowerShell can be installed on demand with, e.g., `Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`.
    In most cases, thread jobs are the better choice, both for performance and type fidelity - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440248/45375) for why.

Comment: I didn't follow this answer exactly, but it got me close enough, so I am marking it as the answer.
Instead of `| Receive-Job -Wait`, I waited until after all the jobs started and ran `while ($true) { (Get-Job | Receive-Job).Line }`.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Tyler. Note that your `while` loop is a tight one. i.e. it'll keep your CPU unnecessarily busy. Piping the jobs to `Receive-Job -Wait` avoids that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. That is good to know.

Comment: The reason I didn't use the `Receive-Job -Wait` is that I was getting this message: `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline
input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input. + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Path...Debug.log:String) [Get-Content], ParameterBind
   ingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost`

Comment: @Tyler, that error message appears to be about `Get-Content`, not `Receive-Job`. However, there was indeed a problem, but not with `Receive-Job` per se: due to a bug in Windows PowerShell (which I didn't see because I tested in PS Core, assuming it would work the same), `Select-String` output objects _do not print_ when retrieved via `Receive-Job`; please see my update, which works around that by piping to `ForEach-Object Line`

Comment: @Tyler, in other words: your tight-loop workaround was effective, due to accessing `.Line` there (and the tight-loop aspect could in principle be avoided with short sleeps between tries), but fixing the problem inside the job script block and sticking with `Receive-Job -Wait` is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: I was still getting the same error message after that change.
It might be something about my environment specifically, but piping `$using:_` into `Get-Content` did not work. I changed it to this `Get-Content -Path $using:_ -Wait | Select-String -Pattern $using:SearchTerm | ForEach-Object Line` and now it works.

Comment: @Tyler: That is curious - it works for me. For robustness, I suggest `Get-Content -LiteralPath ($using:_).FullName -Wait | ...` (I've updated the answer). That way, (a) the argument is guaranteed to expand to a _full path_, and (b) is guaranteed to be interpreted as a _literal_ path (with `-Path`, paths that contain `[` and `]` will be misinterpreted; providing file-info objects _via the pipeline_ avoids that, because it implicitly binds to `-LiteralPath`; while `$using:_` is only an _emulation_ of the original file-info object, it still has the relevant `.PSPath` property).

Comment: Oh I see what I was doing different. I was doing `.FullName` earlier when creating the array. I will change to `-LiteralPath` though

Answer (score 1):

Working off of what you have so far and the comments here is my solution.

```
$SearchPath = "C:\Users\path\Desktop"

$listFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -match [regex]'([a-zA-Z0-9])*\.log' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

Write-Output "Files to be searched: "
Write-Output $listFiles

Read-Host "Press Enter to continue.."
foreach ($path in $listFiles){
    Get-Content -Path $path

}
```

We search the directory and subdirectories specified select the files to your specifications, in this case .log files and save it to `$listFiles`.
In this example I just pause before looping through each file in the list displaying the contents of each file.

[image]

Comment: The reason I had `-Wait` in my question was to allow it to continuously update. This answer stops after the first search completes. If I add `-Wait`, it never moves on to the next path.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that. Was just looking at your updated attempt in #3. 
`-wait` will just stop on the file either until the file is deleted or CTRL+C is pressed. Are you saying you want to use `-wait` but still have it move on to the next file?