# Cannot start job with foreach-object in parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, start-job, foreach-object

I have prepared this script to try to execute in parallel the same function multiple times with different parameters:

```
$myparams = "A", "B","C", "D"

$doPlan = {
    Param([string] $myparam)
        echo "print $myparam"
        # MakeARestCall is a function calling a web service
        MakeARestCall -myparam $myparam
        echo "done"
}

$myparams | Foreach-Object { 
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $doPlan  -ArgumentList $_
}
```

When I run it, the output is

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
79     Job79           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
81     Job81           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
83     Job83           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
85     Job85           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
```

but the actual call to the block (and then to the web service) is not done. If I remove the foreach-object and replace it with a normal sequential foreach block without Start-Job, the webservices are correctly invoked. This means that my issue when I try to run the block in parallel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Background jobs run in independent child processes that share virtually no state with the caller**; specifically:

- They see none of the functions and aliases defined in the calling session, nor manually imported modules, nor manually loaded .NET assemblies.
- They do not load (dot-source) your `$PROFILE` file(s), so they won't see any definitions from there.
- In PowerShell versions 6.x and below (which includes Windows PowerShell), not even the *current location* (directory) was inherited from the caller (it defaulted to `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')`); this was fixed in v7.0.
- The *only* aspect of the calling session's state they do see are copies of the calling process' *environment variables*.
- To make variable values from the caller's session available to the background job, they must be referenced via the `$using:scope` (see [`about_Remote_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Variables)).

  - Note that with values other than strings, primitive types (such as numbers), and a handful of other well-known types, this *can involve a loss of type fidelity*, because the values are marshaled across process boundaries using PowerShell's XML-based serialization and deserialization; this potential loss of type fidelity also affects *output* from the job - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for background information.
  - Using the **much faster and less resource-intensive *thread* jobs, via [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)**, avoids this problem (although all the other limitations apply); `Start-ThreadJob` comes with PowerShell [Core] 6+ and can be installed on demand in Windows PowerShell (e.g., `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser ThreadJob`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612574/45375) for background information.

**Important**: **Whenever you use jobs *for automation***, such as in a script called from the Windows Task Scheduler or in the context of CI / CD, **be sure that you *wait for all jobs to finish* before exiting the script** (via [`Receive-Job -Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) or [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job)), because a script invoked via PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) exits the PowerShell process as a whole, which *kills* any incomplete jobs.

Therefore, unless command `MakeARestCall`:

- happens to be a *script file* (`MakeARestCall.ps1`) or *executable* (`MakeARestCall.exe`) located in one of the directories listed in `$env:Path`
- happens to be a function defined in a *module* that is *auto-loaded*,

your `$doJob` script block will *fail* when executing in the job process', given that neither a `MakeARestCall` function nor alias will be defined.

Your comments suggest that **`MakeARestCall` is indeed a *function*, so in order to make your code work, you'll have to *(re)define the function as part of the script block executed by the job*** (`$doJob`, in your case):

The following simplified example demonstrates the technique:

```
# Sample function that simply echoes its argument.
function MakeARestCall { param($MyParam) "MakeARestCall: $MyParam" }

'foo', 'bar' | ForEach-Object {
  # Note: If Start-ThreadJob is available, use it instead of Start-Job,
  #       for much better performance and resource efficiency.
  Start-Job -ArgumentList $_ { 

    Param([string] $myparam)

    # Redefine the function via its definition in the caller's scope.
    # $function:MakeARestCall returns MakeARestCall's function body
    # which $using: retrieves from the caller's scope, assigning to
    # it defines the function in the job's scope.
    $function:MakeARestCall = $using:function:MakeARestCall

    # Call the recreated MakeARestCall function with the parameter.
    MakeARestCall -MyParam $myparam
  }
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove
```

The above outputs `MakeARestCall: foo` and `MakeARestCall: bar`, demonstrating that the (redefined) `MakeARestCall` function was successfully called in the job's process.

An **alternative approach**:

Make `MakeARestCall` a *script* (`MakeARestCall.ps1`) and call that via its full *path*, to be safe.

E.g., if your script is in the same folder as the *calling* script, invoke  it as
`& $using:PSScriptRoot\MakeARestCall.ps1 -MyParam $myParam`

Of course, if you either don't mind duplicating the function definition or *only* need it in the context of the background jobs, you can simply embed the function definition directly in the script block.

---

#### Simpler and faster PowerShell [Core] 7+ alternative, using `ForEach-Object -Parallel`:

The **`-Parallel`** parameter, introduced to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) in **PowerShell 7**, runs the given script block in a *separate runspace* (thread) for each pipeline input object.

In essence, it is **a simpler, pipeline-friendly way to use *thread jobs* (`Start-ThreadJob`), with the same performance and resource-usage advantages over *background jobs*, and with the added simplicity of directly reporting the threads' output**.

However, the **lack of state sharing discussed with respect to *background jobs* above also applies** to *thread jobs* (even though they run in the *same* process, they do so in isolated PowerShell *runspaces*), so **here too the `MakARestCall` function must be (re)defined (or embedded) inside the script block**<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
# Sample function that simply echoes its argument.
function MakeARestCall { param($MyParam) "MakeARestCall: $MyParam" }

# Get the function definition (body) *as a string*.
# This is necessary, because the ForEach-Object -Parallel explicitly
# disallows referencing *script block* values via $using:
$funcDef = $function:MakeARestCall.ToString()

'foo', 'bar' | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  $function:MakeARestCall = $using:funcDef
  MakeARestCall -MyParam $_
}
```

<sup>Syntax pitfall: `-Parallel` is not a *switch* (flag-type parameter), but takes the script block to run in parallel as its argument; in other words: `-Parallel` must be placed directly before the script block.</sup>

The above directly emits outputs from the parallel threads, as it arrives - but note that this means that the output is *not* guaranteed to arrive in input order; that is, a thread created later may situationally returns its output before an earlier thread.

A simple example:

```
PS> 3, 1 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Start-Sleep $_; "$_" }
1  # !! *Second* input's thread produced output *first*.
3
```

In order to show the outputs *in input order* - which invariably requires waiting for all threads to finish before showing output, you can add the **`-AsJob` switch**:

- Instead of direct output, a *single, lightweight* (thread-based) job object is then returned, which returns a *single* job of type `PSTaskJob` comprising multiple *child* jobs, one for each parallel runspace (thread); you can manage it with the usual `*-Job` cmdlets and access the individual child jobs via the `.ChildJobs` property.

By waiting for the overall job to *complete*, receiving its outputs via [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) then shows them in *input order*:

```
PS> 3, 1 | ForEach-Object -AsJob -Parallel { Start-Sleep $_; "$_" } |
      Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove
3  # OK, first input's output shown first, due to having waited.
1
```

---

[1] Alternatively, redefine your `MakeARestCall` function as a *filter function* (`Filter`) that implicitly operates on *pipeline* input, via `$_`, so you can use its definition as the `ForEach-Object -Parallel` script block as-is:

```
# Sample *filter* function that echoes the pipeline input it is given.
Filter MakeARestCall { "MakeARestCall: $_" }

# Pass the filter function's definition (which is a script block)
# directly to ForEach-Object -Parallel
'foo', 'bar' | ForEach-Object -Parallel $function:MakeARestCall
```