# Write to external array inside a running powershell job

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, background-process, get-wmiobject, powershell-jobs

I am trying to write data to external array while running a powershell job-

This is my code sample that I' m trying-

```
$datafromJob = @()
$wmijobs = @()
foreach ($c in $computers) {
    $wmijobs += Start-Job -Name WMIInventory -ScriptBlock {
        $jobdata = get-wmiobject -ComputerName $args[0] -Class win32_computersystem -Credential $Cred -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($Err.length) {
            Add-content -Path D:\InventoryError.log -Force -Value $Err
            $details = @{
                Domain       = "Error"
                Manufacturer = "Error"
                Computer     = $args[0]
                Name         = "Error"
            }
            $args[3] += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }
        if ($jobdata.length) {
            $details = @{
                Domain       = $jobdata.Domain
                Manufacturer = $jobdata.Manufacturer
                Computer     = $args[2]
                Name         = $jobdata.Name
            }
            $args[3] += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }
        -ArgumentList $c, $Cred, "Test", $datafromJob
    }
}
```

Expecting Output in $datafromJob Variable, but the end of job and loop  variable is empty, M not getting how it will work, anyhelp,

Do let me know if any queries on this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background jobs run in a separate (child) process, so you fundamentally cannot directly update values in the *caller*'s scope from them.<sup>[1]</sup>

Instead, make your job script block produce *output* that the caller can capture with [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Receive-Job).

A simple example:

```
# Create a 10-element array in a background job and output it.
# Receive-Job collects the output.
$arrayFromJob = Start-Job { 1..10 } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Note: If what you output from a background job are complex objects, they will typically *not* retain their original type and instead be custom-object *emulations*, due to the limitations of PowerShell's XML-based cross-process serialization infrastructure; only a limited set of well-known types deserialize with type fidelity, including primitive .NET types, hashtables and `[pscustomobject]` instances (with the type-fidelity limitations again applying to their properties and entries).  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for background information.

---

A few asides:

- There is no need to call `Start-Job` / `Get-WmiObject` in a loop, because the latter's `-ComputerName` parameter can accept an *array* of target computers to connect to in a single call.

  - Since the target computers are then queried *in parallel*, you may not need a background job (`Start-Job`) at all.
- The CIM cmdlets (e.g.,[`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/CimCmdlets/Get-CimInstance)) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, **the WMI cmdlets should be avoided**, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore.

  - Remote use of the CIM cmdlets by default requires that the target computers be set up for WS-Management connections, as they implicitly are if PowerShell remoting is enabled on them - see [about_Remote_Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements); alternatively, however, you can use the DCOM protocol (which is what the WMI cmdlets used) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375) for more information.

Applying the above to your case:

```
# Create a CIM session that targets all computers.
# By default, the WS-Management protocol is used, which target computers
# are implicitly set up for if PowerShell remoting is enabled on them.
# However, you can opt to use DCOM - as the WMI cmdlets did - as follows:
#   -SessionOption (New-CimSessionOption -Protocol DCOM)
$session = New-CimSession -ComputerName $computers -Credential $Cred

# Get the CIM data from all target computers in parallel.
[array] $cimData = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $session -Class win32_computersystem -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Domain       = $_.Domain
      Manufacturer = $_.Manufacturer
      Computer     = $_.ComputerName
      Name         = $_.Name
    }
  }

# Cleanup: Remove the session.
Remove-CimSession $session

# Add error information, if any.
if ($Err) {
  Set-Content D:\InventoryError.log -Force -Value $Err
  $cimData += $Err | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Domain       = "Error"
      Manufacturer = "Error"
      Computer     = $_.ComputerName
      Name         = "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

**Caveat re targeting a large number of computers at once**:

- As of this writing, neither the [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/Get-CimInstance) help topic nor the conceptual [about_CimSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_cimsession) topic discuss *connection throttling* (limiting the number of concurrent connections to remote computers to prevent overwhelming the system).
- PowerShell's general-purpose [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) remoting command, by contrast, has a `-ThrottleLimit` parameter that defaults to `32`. Note that PowerShell remoting must first be enabled on the target computers in order to be able to use `Invoke-Command` on them remotely - see [about_Remote_Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements).

Therefore, to have more control over how the computers are targeted in parallel, consider combining `Invoke-Command` with *local* invocation of `Get-CimInstance` *on each remote machine*; for instance:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ThrottleLimit 16 {
    Get-CimInstance win32_computersystem  
}  -Credential $Cred -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction
```

Also passing a *sessions-options object* to `Invoke-Command`'s `-SessionOption` parameter, created with [`New-PSSessionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption), additionally gives you control over various *timeouts*.

---

<sup>[1] In a script block executed in a background job, the automatic `$args` variable contains deserialized *copies* of the values passed by the caller - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for background information.

Note that the usually preferable, thread-based `Start-ThreadJob` cmdlet - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612574/45375) - *can* receive live references to reference-type instances in the caller's scope, though *modifying* such objects then requires explicit synchronization, if multiple thread jobs access them in parallel; the same applies to the PowerShell 7+ [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-7) feature.</sup>

Comment: hey just an update `Get-CimInstance` does'nt accepts `-Credential` parameter, to use custom credential one will have to use `New-CimSession` to store credential and computer detail, refer [this url](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36875.powershell-managing-service-s-using-wmi-cim-and-get-service-cmdlet.aspx) for reference

Comment: I appreciate the correction @Vino - sorry for not checking that myself first; I've updated the answer accordingly. Since I cannot really test these things myself, it would be great if you could let us know if the session-based approach now shown in the answer works, and perhaps also if `Get-CimInstance` is suitable for targeting 1000+ servers - or whether PS remoting (`Invoke-Command`) must be used.

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible with threadjobs, but it probably wouldn't work well in your case.  Arrays aren't thread safe.

```
$a = 1,2,3
start-threadjob { $b = $using:a; $b[0] = 2 } | receive-job -wait -auto
$a

2
2
3
```

Hmm, thread safe updating of a dictionary collection from the bottom here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/

```
$threadSafeDictionary =
[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()

Get-Process | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $dict = $using:threadSafeDictionary
    $dict.TryAdd($_.ProcessName, $_)
}

$threadSafeDictionary["pwsh"]
```

"Concurrent bag":

```
$threadSafeArray =
[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[object]]::new()

1..10 | foreach-object -parallel { 
    $array = $using:threadSafeArray
    $array.Add($_)
} 

$threadSafeArray

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: This answer works extremely well for Powershell 7's foreach-object -parallel!

The `$using` was the trick for me, is this because Powershell considers this a Remote Variable? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7)

Comment: @aolszowka The foreach parallel loop runs in another runspace like start-threadjob.

Answer (score 0):

As per @mklement0 suggestion, have updated my script,

```
$wmijobs = @()
foreach ($c in $computers) {
    $wmijobs += Start-Job -Name WMIInventory -ScriptBlock {
        $jobdata = get-CimInstance -ComputerName $args[0] -Class win32_computersystem -Credential $Cred -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($Err.length) {
            Add-content -Path D:\InventoryError.log -Force -Value $Err
            $details = @{
                Domain       = "Error"
                Manufacturer = "Error"
                Computer     = $args[0]
                Name         = "Error"
            }
          return New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }
        if ($jobdata) {
            $details = @{
                Domain       = $jobdata.Domain
                Manufacturer = $jobdata.Manufacturer
                Computer     = $args[2]
                Name         = $jobdata.Name
            }
            return New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }
        -ArgumentList $c, $Cred, "Test", $datafromJob
    }
}
$wmijobs = $wmijobs | get-job | receive-job -AutoRemoveJob -wait
```

Comment: Definitely an improvement, but that `Get-CimInstance` too can accept an _array_ of computer names, which then targets all computers _in parallel_, so I suspect you don't need `Start-Job` at all - please see the update to my answer.