# Powershell foreach loop spawning jobs, but they're not running concurrently

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script that monitors a directory for changes, and when detected, spawns a job to deal with the file:

```
get-childitem | foreach-object {
   $name = $_.Name
   $newname = "work-"+$name

   Rename-Item -Path $name -NewName $newname
   Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
      $newvar = $args[0]
      ffmpeg -i $newvar -acodec flac -f ogg $newvar".flac"
      } -ArgumentList $newname
   }
}
```

When running the script, jobs are spawned correctly, but processing doesn't commence after the third job.  For example:

```
Job 1 --> Complete
Job 2 --> Complete
Job 3 --> Complete
Job 4 --> Running
Job 5 --> Running
Job 6 --> Running
```

And the script does not progress.  Jobs 4-6 are left perpetually in the running state.  There is no output file created from `ffmpeg`, so I know the script block hasn't run.

I have tried setting `Set-PSDebug -Trace 2` to monitor the script - variables are correctly being set, and jobs are spawning correctly.  However, as the script is running, I can't do a `Receive-Job` or `Get-Job` to see what's going on inside of them.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: You can `receive-job -keep` for a job that is running to see what could be going on

Comment: As an aside: if feasible, consider using much more lightweight  _thread_-based jobs instead, via  `Start-ThreadJob` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612574/45375).

Comment: If `Receive-Job` shows no output and the jobs are still running, the likeliest explanation is that the `ffmpeg` calls _haven't finished yet_.

Comment: As an aside: `$newvar".flac"` is better expressed as `"$newvar.flac"`. Otherwise, you'll be in for a surprise if you try `"foo/"$newvar`, for instance (compound string arguments mustn't start with a _quoted_ token - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375).